# Import package from npm to react native

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native

I want to import this npm package from npm but it returns error

I have init new project and done this

```
npm install @google/maps --save

var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps')
```

Error is this
[image]

this is error log

```
error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `url` from `/Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules/@google/maps/lib/internal/make-api-call.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  /Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules
,   /Users/barron9/Downloads/node_modules

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
    at ResolutionRequest._resolveNodeDependency (/Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:394:11)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:141:29)
    at dependencyNames.map.name (/Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:145:59)
    at Array.map (native)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveModuleDependencies (/Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:145:42)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:169:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
Bundling `index.android.js`  94.3% (405/417), failed.
error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `url` from `/Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules/@google/maps/lib/internal/make-api-call.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  /Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules
,   /Users/barron9/Downloads/node_modules
```

Comment: what happens if you uninstall this package, everything is ok?

Comment: yes if I delete import I shows initial app perfectly

Comment: pls post logs from installing package through `npm`

Comment: ok.............. error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `url` from `/Users/barron9/Downloads/meteor/node_modules/@google/maps/lib/internal/make-api-call.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:

Comment: i am trying to install and import these core modules yes url and crypt ..

Comment: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `crypto`

Comment: did you also install "crypto" and all other missing libraries yet? I'm just afraid this may not work with react-native

Comment: yes worked with nodeify but now some other errors

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
import googleMapsClient from '@google/maps';
```

Otherwise, that package does not target React-Native, I think.

Would you consider using the correct package for react-native, which works well in my react-native project:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps

Comment: Oh I see, so maybe there's still some missing libraries. Where did you get the tutorial for that google-map package, maybe extra steps are necessary, could you please give me the link, thanks

Comment: works normally on nodejs project without anything try it no tutorial npm install @google/maps https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps

Comment: I see, probably the package is for react, not for react-native! Could you please see my above edited version, which links to another good package?